# How can you access a VM using Vagrant private network on different ports?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant

I'm running a private network Vagrant environment with a specified ip address and hostname. I can currently access the http version on port 80, but I'd also like to be able to access it on port 8080.

I added something like this:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
```

But, when I visit my site on port 8080, I get an unavailable page error. Port 80 still works. how can I properly access my VM on a different port if the forwarded port doesn't work for private network?

Answer (score 3):

Remember Vagrant Port forwarding **ONLY** works for the default NAT networking (using VirtualBox NAT), not private or public.

So if you want to access the service via private IP on port 8080, you either listen it on port 8080 or use iptables to forward packets.

e.g.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Comment: I don't want to listen on port 8080, because my production environment runs on port 80, so I want vagrant to mimic that as much as possible. I'm not running on Linux so iptables isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am working with a rails application and it is my Vagrantfile and I access to my web service very well.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = "web"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 3000, guest: 3000  
end
```

I did it following the instructions of [Vagrant site.](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html)

Comment: This *appears* to work because you're "mapping" the same ports.  You're actually just going directly to the 3000 port on your private network IP.  If you were to try mapping different ports, you'd find the host port would not work.